# How do I fix pip not being recognized as a command?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a Python package, but in CMD it says that pip is not a command. I've looked at other posts, and the `sudo` command also doesn't work. I know I have python because `py` command works but `sudo` and `pip` won't work. How do I fix this?

I've tried running `sudo easy_install pip` because some other post said to do it, but it doesn't not work.

Comment: which version of python are you using? have you tried pip3 command?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.8 and pip3 also does not exist.

Comment: Which OS are you currently on?  Windows / MacOS / Linux?

Comment: are you using windows or linux?

Comment: Check your environment variables first.

Comment: I see you said `CMD` instead of `bash`, so I guess you are working on Windows. Windows doesn't have `sudo`, this is a Linux command. Another point, please try to run `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Your_Python_Install_Root;C:\Your_Python_Install_Root\Scripts`, then run `pip install something`

Comment: Did you marked "Add Python to PATH" option while installing -> check it [python-installation](https://realpython.com/installing-python/)

Comment: For what it's worth, `sudo` in a Unix command which has no hope of doing anything useful on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the pip to PATH environment variable.

> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"

And then run this command with cmd as Admin rights:

> python -m pip install [packagename]

Hope this will help you out.